# KCQL where clause

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using cassandra source connector provided by data mountaineer. What is missing is the use of where clause in KCQL. I want to write kcql in such a manner that it will send data on different topics depending on the value of a column. For example if I have following records:

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    store:"102"
  },
  { 
    id:2,
    store:"105"
  },
  {
    id:3,
    store:"102"
   },
   {
    id:4,
    store:"105"
   }
 ]
```

Then I want to send data where store=105 to one topic and the data where store=102 to another topic.